# attribute error: when trying to write in form xml

Tags: python, xml, odoo, attributeerror, openerp-7

I am trying to update my form view xml. here is my code:

```
def update_column(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        for id in ids:
            temp=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
            fields={'myname':temp.name,'mytype':temp.data_type}

            self._columns.update(fields)
            print (self._columns)
        result = super(deg_form, self).create(cr,uid,{},context=None)    
        return result


def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(deg_form,self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu)
        objn = self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr, uid, 145)
        if view_type=='form':
       str_fields=str(res['fields'])
       str_fields=str_fields[:len(str_fields)-1]+ ", 'father_name' :{'selectable': True, 'views': {},'type':'char', 'string': '"+objn.name+"', 'store': True,'size': 128}}"
       res['fields']=eval(str_fields)
              temp_arch="""<field name="father_name" />"""      
       fields_string=res['arch']
       index_of_end_group=fields_string.find('</group>')
       fields_string=fields_string[:index_of_end_group] + " " +temp_arch + " "+fields_string[index_of_end_group(inlove)
              res['arch']=fields_string
        return res
```

but i am getting error

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_type'
```

here is my stacktrace:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 90, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/netsvc.py", line 295, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 614, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 198, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/system/myform.py", line 131, in update_column
    result = super(deg_form, self).create(cr,uid,{},context=None)
  File "/home/arsalan/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4372, in create
    bool_fields = [x for x in self._columns.keys() if self._columns[x]._type=='boolean']
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_type'
```

I am trying since 2 days and now i am out of any ideas. any help or guide to solution is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of `self._columns` is a **unicode** object. The reason is that you update `self._columns` with a wrong type of data. It keeps `{'field_name':openerp.osv.fields.date object}` but here:

```
temp=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
fields={'myname':temp.name,'mytype':temp.data_type}
self._columns.update(fields)
```

you update **_columns** with weird values.

Comment: any solution for that??

Comment: Change your fields dict for something like {'column_name': fields.integer('Field object')}